# Is Visual Studio made using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Just wondering if Visual Studio is developed in the IDE that is Visual Studio? Maybe VS2010 was made using VS2008?

Comment: No, VS2010 was made with VS2010.  You can tell because VS2010 needs VS2010 specific components to run.  The process is called "bootstrapping".  Using your own tools to create the next version is called "dog-fooding".

Comment: Hans, can you give examples, I am intrigued by your answer?